# Getting row number from database when using where and order by statements

Tags: php, mysql

Ok I have tried several ways to do this but none of them work, so I have no code to show. But I will explain this the best I can.

I have a contest script, and I am wanting to add a line that will show the user which place they are in under the list of current winners. So I want the table to look like this.

```
-----------------------------------------
| Place |    User   | Prize | Completed |
|   1   | Someuser1 | $5.00 |     5     |
|   2   | Someuser2 | $2.50 |     3     |
|   3   | Someuser3 | $1.25 |     2     |
|   20  |    You    |  ---  |     1     |
-----------------------------------------
```

I have everything for the so called someusers, but I want to be able to count where the current user that is viewing the page can see where they stand in the contest. What kind of query could I run to get the place in which the current user is.

I hope that makes sense with no code.

Table structure

```
    Column   |  Type | Null |  Default
--------------------------------------
    id       |int(11)|  No  |   
    username |text   |  No  |   
    completed|int(11)|  No  |
```

Comment: You need to post at least how your tables looks like. Specially where the `User` column is coming from.

Comment: Disregard my previous comment; I think I get it now.

Comment: @Prash I want to get the place value of the user that it is viewing the page. I figured it would fall under counting the rows, but I have never tried something like this before.

Comment: @BrunoVieira I assumed you were talking about the table structure, if it was i have added the structure above

Comment: @kira423 exactly that, dumb me was trying to ask you for your table structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.  One is to count how many rows have a higher rank than the given row:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Place, t.*
FROM TheTable t
LEFT OUTER JOIN TheTable t2 ON t.Prize < t2.Prize
GROUP BY t.id
HAVING Place <= 3 OR user = 'You';
```

Another is to use a session variable to track the ranking:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT (@row := COALESCE(@row, 0)+1) AS Place, t.*
  FROM TheTable t
  ORDER BY Prize DESC) r
WHERE Place <= 3 OR user = 'You';
```

Comment: This seems like it would only work if the prizes were in the same table as the users?

Comment: @kira423 the man who answered probably wrote the book you teacher used to teach you MySQL and in a way helped me with my MySQL server (through percona tuning) so I didn't even think about his answer, because it's surely correct

Comment: @kira423, yes, I'm making assumptions about the table structure, but the OP wasn't very complete in his description.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information.  Best way to ask questions on StackOverflow is be specific about what you want to happen, what you tried (show code), and how the result isn't what you expected.  Suggest you open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, from what I understand, there are two ways I can think of doing it.

1. Have 2 queries. First query to get the top 3, then one to get the user place

   ```
   # First query to get top three

   if (  user not in top three) {
        $db->prepare('SELECT whatever FROM table WHERE user = ?')->execute(array($user));
   }
   ```
2. Retrieve all the results, display the top three and display the one with the current user.

EDIT: Bill's answer seems better :)